# How to create an indicator that sends alert, when current price crosses a preset price?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

How to create an indicator in pinescript 4, that sends alert, when current price crosses a preset price? So when current price crosses the (preset) price of 105 usd, I want it to send an alert.

I should also be able to easy edit the preset price.

I want to use it combination with something else. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ta.cross()` function for that.

```
in_price = input.float(105.0)

is_crossed = ta.cross(close, in_price)
alertcondition(is_crossed, "Price crossed")
```

Remember, when you set your alert, Tradingview will take a snapshot of your chart and run it on its server. So, that means, if you change the price input afterwards, it will have no affect. You need to set a new alert for that.

**Edit: v4**

```
in_price = input(105.0, type=input.float)

is_crossed = cross(close, in_price)
alertcondition(is_crossed, "Price crossed")
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your help. I couldn't get it to work in pine 4. Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 17: Could not find function or function reference 'ta.cross'.
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 17: Could not find function or function reference 'ta.cross'.
line 9: 'input.float' is not a function.

Comment: Please see my edit.